# Is there a way to see the output of a line of python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm working on making a terminal in a pygame window. This is for an interpreter I'm working on. I've tried all the things where you run it to see the output with multiprocess, but is there a way to execute the line of code once and see the terminal output? Preferably while also executing the line of code (eg. `a = 5` a can be referenced later).

--edit--

I'm trying to make a virtual terminal in the pygame window, and need to be able to see the terminal output of a python command.

Comment: Most IDE's have debug features that allow you to incrementally step through the code and see what;s going on. You could also insert print statements within your code to help debug.  Would it be possible to provide additional information?

Comment: python `:=` or walrus operator may be what you need. it will evaluate the entire thing and then store it in a variable that can then be accessed later. likely with a print statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 2 ways that I think will help the most:

**1 Debug**
You can try to use the debug function that most IDEs have to step over and execute one line at a time. So you would add a breakpoint at 'a' and then step over.

**2 Print**
You can use the print statements and print your values as the code runs. So you would print(a)

Comment: Makes sense, but is there a way to see if something such as "import pygame" would print something out? I'm not trying to print anything, just see what it would print.

Comment: importing modules does not print out anything. You can try pygame.version.ver, but I don't think that's what you are looking for

Comment: yes, but I'd like to be able to see what things print no matter what. some libraries print things when you call functions, some things like pygame print stuff out no matter what, and I'd like to be able to automaticly see what they do

Comment: I Don't think that you can do that, but I might be wrong